# NullPointerException error on context when calling sharedPref from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I keep getting a `NullPointerException`  on the context when I try to initiate my `SharedPreference` init from a fragment.

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
            at c.c.modular.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:68)
            at c.c.ProfileCompletedFragment.setupData(ProfileCompletedFragment.java:75)
            at c.c.ProfileCompletedFragment.passDataToFragment(ProfileCompletedFragment.java:210)
            at c.c.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:287)
```

Here is the initializer:

```
// init
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;

            pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor = pref.edit();

    }
```

Here is the call in the fragment:

```
private void setupData() {
        //sessions manager
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

        //establishing db
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        count = 0;

    }
```

EDIT:

What I have realized is that getActivity is null due to the fact that the fragment is not yet attached to the activity itself, trying to figure out how to attach it so I can make a call to the activity... This is my new attempt in the edit below... same issue...

```
 profileJoinedFrag = new ProfileJoinedFragment();
        profileCompletedFrag = new ProfileCompletedFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, profileCompletedFrag).commit();

        //Setting up fragment
        String[] tabTitles =  {"Posts", "Joins"};
        adapter = new TabAdapter(fm, profileCompletedFrag, profileJoinedFrag, tabTitles);

//        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.profilePager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.profileTabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        //default place send
        //

        pager.setCurrentItem(0);
        profileCompletedFrag.passDataToFragment(userId);
```

Comment: context is null check  that

Answer (score 2):

Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` instead of context use application context

Comment: getActivity().getApplicationContext() use this

Comment: getActivity is null that is the issue check the Edit I posted above

Comment: Use FragmentActivity() instead of Activity

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `null` to `SessionManager` because `getActivity()` is returning `null`. That means your `Fragment`is not attached to any `Activity` when you run `setupData()`.

Try to call `setupData()` on a `Fragment`method that runs only when the `Fragment` is attached for sure, like `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.

Take a look at the [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) and pick a method that makes sense in your code.

**EDIT**

I can see you are trying to pass arguments to the `Fragment` by calling a method on the `Fragment`. The correct way to do it is to pass it a `Bundle`, like this:

```
Fragment f = new MyFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("userId", userId);
f.setArguments(args);
```

And then on the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int userId = args.getInt("userId", 0);
//... Do whatever with the argument
setupData();
```

And like I said before, if you call your `setupData()` method inside the `onCreate()` the `getActivity()` call won't return `null`.

Comment: Exactly this is the issue, trying to figure this out... the problem is trying to figure out how to make sense of fragment manager... this is what I tried... look at the edited code

Comment: Thanks is it more efficient to pass the args in than using an interface to make a call to the activity? Because the answer I posted is how I am currently solving this

Comment: The interface it's usually used when the Fragment wants to make some action on the Activity, not to make the Activity call it back with some arguments. I'd still prefer passing arguments on the Fragment creation, but your solution certainly works. The efficiency should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to init

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

instead of `session = new SessionManager(getActivity());`

Comment: The problem is that getActivity is null, because I have a fragment created but it might be that it is not attach to the activity, any ideas on how to attach it without fragmentManager since the fragments are not v4 support lib frags

Comment: Please debug properly and see what is going on while you use SharedPreferences in fragment.

Comment: the getActivity is null check the edit I posted above

Answer (score 0):

After taking in what MadEqua has mentioned I have solved it like this if anyone else is looking for a solution...

I added a communicator from the fragment to the activity and an attach method to the fragment.

Therefore once the fragment is attached to the activity, a call is made to the activity to initiate the id to be passed to the fragment... like so:

Fragment:

```
//since fragment is loaded before activity
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        setupData();

        //TODO depending which frag to start on then have it make this call
        ((ProfileActivity) getActivity()).passDataToActivity(true);
    }
```

Activity (implements the activityCommunicator interface):

```
@Override
    public void passDataToActivity(Boolean someValue) {
            profileJoinedFrag.passDataToFragment(userId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: `public String getValueFromSharedPref(String key, String defaultvalue)
    {
        sp =getContext().getSharedPreferences("preference name",MODE_PRIVATE);
        return (sp.getString(key,defaultvalue));
    }`